# EAS Update doesn't allow uppercase in scheme

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

Expo SDK version 48. EAS CLI version 3.15.1. Bare workflow.

I’m having an issue with trying to get eas update working in my app. I inherited this app and already had a bundle identifier set up like this com.name.NAME. Now this isn’t an issue until trying to set up eas update. I got everything up and running and then whenever I run eas update, I’m getting this error:

:heavy_multiplication_x: Failed to publish updates
Manifest Validation Error:
scheme:‘scheme’ should match pattern “[a-z0-9+.-]*$”
scheme:should be array
scheme:should match exactly one schema in oneOf
This is likely a problem with your app.json, or app.config.js
Request ID: 3b13113d-ffd9-4b11-b900-41a3398556c3

I know this is happening because my scheme is listed as com.name.NAME and really needs to be com.name.name, but since this app is already in the app store, I would rather not change that since it will create a whole new app. Is there anyway to work around this, or am I out of luck?